# MySQL LOAD DATA Error can't resolve...!

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/abc.txt' INTO TABLE test1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|';
ERROR 13 (HY000): Can't get stat of '/abc.txt' (Errcode: 2)
```

I used LOAD DATA as per the syntax. But getting the above error. can anybody tell what is the error..!?
I tried searching google dev.mysql can't find what error it is??

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show us the "stat /abc.txt" output. possibly related to file permissions error. http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/206087

Comment: On which machine does it exist, server or client?

Comment: I m using localhost on client and server on same machine

Comment: above one is the output when I used stat abc.txt

Comment: Does the `mysqld` process have permission to access the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the file is on your MYSQL server try using the full path.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/tmp/abc.txt' INTO TABLE test1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|';
```

If the file isn't on the server and it is on your local machine, and your user has access to SCP files between the servers ( try this

```
scp abc.txt mysqlserver:
```

) then you should be able to do this (using full path again) ..

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/tmp/abc.txt' INTO TABLE test1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|';
```

If that doesn't work.. try renaming the file to test1.txt and using the 'mysqlimport' command?

Comment: That was the clue I was seeking.  On EC2, copying the file from user directory (`/home/me/mydata/mydata.csv`) to `/var/tmp/mydata.csv` worked

Answer (score 0):

Login to the mysql console using the following flag:

```
mysql -uroot -p --local-infile
```

and then enter the password.

After that execute the load data command as follows:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/abc.txt' INTO TABLE test1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|';
```